# Read standard input and print standard output using function bool.getCharacter(char* c)

Tags: c++

a. Read single character and print it to standard input.
b. Use the following function to the standard input. The function was bool.getCharacter(char* c).

```
Here's what I've done so far

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

#define LENGTH 101

int main(void) {
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

 int main() {

char c;
bool getCharacter(char* c) {

std::cout << &a << " " << a << std::endl;
    while(std::cin >> *c) {
    if(cin >> *c) {
        cout << true << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        cout << false << endl;
    return c;

}
       return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

error on line 11: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token

Comment: you cannot define functions inside functions, thats basically what the error tries to tell you

Comment: you are putting a function inside the main() cpp fuction. that should be the error. try to declare it outside main()

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm not going to solve all your problems, but let's start with this and see if you get further.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

#define LENGTH 101

using std::cin;
using std::cout;

bool getCharacter(char* c) {
    std::cout << &a << " " << a << std::endl;
    if (std::cin >> *c) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main(int, char **) {
     char c;
     while (getCharacter(&c)) {
          cout << c << endl;
     }
}
```

Basically, you tried nesting methods, which is really not allowed. And your getCharacter() method was doing way too much. It's supposed to get a character, not do anything else, and then you have to actually call it.